# I am unable to access newly installed python 3 modules/libraries in IDLE in an Ubuntu VM

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu, virtualbox, python-idle

I have a python web crawler that I want to write the information it parses to a MySQL database.

I have MySQL and python and everything installed. My issue is that I need a library to interface between python and MySQL. I try to install a library using apt-get or pip. It downloads correctly. But when I go to IDLE and try to import a module from the library it just says that there is no module.

I've been searching for a while, but every example I see is problem with people who aren't able to install at all. It seems like my problem is that the terminal and IDLE are somehow running different versions of Python? When I try to look up the version of python in the terminal it says I'm running 2.7.10, but in IDLE it says 3.4.3. I couldn't figure out a way to phrase this problem in a way that found any useful results, so sorry if this question is asked like every day.

More information:

Windows 10 OS running Oracle VM VirtualBox with Ubuntu 15.10.

Terminal says Python 2.7.10, IDLE says Python is 3.4.3

Libraries I've tried installing through apt-get, pip, and/or easy_install: [PyMySQL](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL), [MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html), mysql.connector (apparently I can't post any more links)

Error messages:
In terminal:

```
draav@Ubuntu-VirtualBox:~$ pip3 install PyMySQL3
Downloading/unpacking PyMySQL3
  Downloading PyMySQL3-0.5.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-cj27_k_q/PyMySQL3/setup.py) egg_info for package PyMySQL3

Installing collected packages: PyMySQL3
  Running setup.py install for PyMySQL3

Successfully installed PyMySQL3
Cleaning up...
```

In IDLE:

```
>>> import PyMySQL3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    import PyMySQL3
ImportError: No module named 'PyMySQL3'
```

Comment: It would help if you could copy and paste the IDLE session text, including the commands you're typing and the error messages you see.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `python3` and `pip3` to refer to Python 3.x installation, because simple `python` and `pip` by default refer to Python 2.x.